# Consulta en LINQ, Como concatenar campos

Tags: c#, base-de-datos, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql

Buenas tardes,

tengo el siguiente left join

```
var innerJoin = from emp in db.Tbl_Empleado
                        join mb in db.Tbl_MarcacionesBiometrico 
                        on emp.EmpId equals mb.EmpId into MarcBio
                        from mb2 in MarcBio.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        join hr in db.Tbl_Horario
                        on emp.EmpId equals hr.EmpId into Horas
                        from hr2 in Horas.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        select new
                        {
                            EmpId = emp.EmpId,
                            EmpNombre = emp.EmpNombre,
                            MarBioAnio = mb2.MarBioAnio,
                            MarBioMes = mb2.MarBioMes,
                            MarBioDia = mb2.MarBioDia,
                            MarBioHora = mb2.MarBioHora,
                            MarBioMinuto = mb2.MarBioMinuto,
                            HrHoraEntrada = hr2.HorHoraEntrada,
                            HrHoraInicioDescanso = hr2.HorHoraInicioDescanso,
                            HrHoraFinDescanso = hr2.HorHoraFinDescanso,
                            HrHoraSalida = hr2.HorHoraSalida,
                            HrDia = hr2.HorDia

                        };
```

Mi esquema relacional es el siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero es poder **unir los campos MarBioAnio, MarBio,MarBiosMes** **como un solo campo**, tambien necesito u**nir los campos MarBioHora, MarBioMinuto como un solo campo** y no se como hacer eso en linq.

De paso quiero saber si me podrían ayudar también necesito poder comparar la marcaciones que el empleado hizo en el biometrico con su horario en base a ello poder determinar las horas extras.

Comment: Cuando dices que lo quieres como uno, en que formato exactamente es lo quieres?

Comment: Los primeros tres campos los quiero convertir a tipo fecha y los otros campos a tipo time o no se si pudiera unir todos los campos como un solo campo datetime

Answer (score 2):

Utilizando al concatenacion normal puedes lograrlo:

```
var innerJoin = from emp in db.Tbl_Empleado
                        join mb in db.Tbl_MarcacionesBiometrico 
                        on emp.EmpId equals mb.EmpId into MarcBio
                        from mb2 in MarcBio.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        join hr in db.Tbl_Horario
                        on emp.EmpId equals hr.EmpId into Horas
                        from hr2 in Horas.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        select new
                        {
                            EmpId = emp.EmpId,
                            EmpNombre = emp.EmpNombre,

                            Concatenacion1 = mb2.MarBioAnio + " " + mb2.MarBioMes  + " " + mb2.MarBioDia,
                            Concatenacion2 = mb2.MarBioHora + " " + mb2.MarBioMinuto,

                            HrHoraEntrada = hr2.HorHoraEntrada,
                            HrHoraInicioDescanso = hr2.HorHoraInicioDescanso,
                            HrHoraFinDescanso = hr2.HorHoraFinDescanso,
                            HrHoraSalida = hr2.HorHoraSalida,
                            HrDia = hr2.HorDia

                        };
```

Comment: Gracias, ahorita hare los cambios.

Comment: Einer, una pregunta. No se si me puedes ayudar, como puedo hacer para poder recorrer la coleccion y comparar los valores. Soy nuevo en esto, si me pudieses ayudar te lo agradecería mucho.